# How to query all PBI's historical changes from a team project in TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In TFS query builder, I would like to build a query to get all PBIs historical state changes together with the date when that change occured. For instance :

PBI : User Story 1
    [History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZPsF.png)

PBI : User Story 2
    [History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJPZ0.png)
.
.
.

Basicly I want the History tab of each PBI shown in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no this kind of workitem query directly return what you need.

Since you need  the specific dates/times on which  state transitions occurred. You should use TFS API to get the workitem history, and enumerating through the revision history of the work item to get the state transition history. More details please take a look at this useful  article here: [TFS SDK: Work Item History Visualizer using TFS API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243653/TFS-SDK-Work-Item-History-Visualizer-using-TFS-API)

Comment: Thank you, this has made my job much easier!